# Set borderColor to UIView

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, uicolor, cgcolor

Is there any possible ways i can set a border color on a UI View?

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
newView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
newView.layer.borderWidth = 1
newView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually now this made it work:

```
newView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
newView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
newView.layer.borderWidth = 2
```